# how to use Android - notifyDataSetChanged() after delete an item?

Tags: java, android

I search a lot of similar question...all of them say I must use something like this code:

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after this code: `bookmarks.remove(pos);`

but you can see...in BookMarkActivity  class do not use `arrayAdapter`

```
public class BookMarkActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.message);

        // Reading all contacts
        final ArrayList<BookMark> bookmarks = (ArrayList<BookMark>) db.getAllBookMarks();
        BuildingAdapter adapter = new BuildingAdapter(context);
        // ADDED
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        lv.setAdapter(new BookmarkAdapter(this, bookmarks));

        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int pos, long id) {

                bookmarks.remove(pos);

                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I am new in android...but I try change code with this:

```
private ArrayAdapter<BookMark> arrayAdapter;
arrayAdapter = new BookmarkAdapter(this, bookmarks);
```

but no success! the listview do not be refresh after delete one item!

Comment: You also set your adapter, right: `lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);`?

Comment: @karaokyo No and now works..thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView displays some data stored in an ArrayList.

When element remove or add in ArrayList, you have to tell the list that the source of the data had changed to show the new data.

So, that is where notifyDatasetChanged() comes in. It tells the ListView that the data has been modified so please reflect the changed data.

```
final BookmarkAdapter adapter = new BookmarkAdapter(this, bookmarks);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and after remove element use below line.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Just add two lines on the button/imageView click listeners.**

```
delete.setOnClickListener {
                list.removeAt(pos)
                notifyItemRemoved(pos)
            }
```